# Any iOS Storyboard equivalent for Android development?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, storyboard

Is there any iOS Storyboard equivalent for Android development?

iOS Storyboard is fantastic that saves us a lot of time writing code. It is almost like a direct wireframe/prototype to final development too.

Anything on Android development which can perform the same?

Comment: hey brother check out https://www.figma.com/ tool on internet to design the wireframe and Prototypes . its not perfect for Android developement but still usefull .

Comment: @Sumit Figma is just a design tool...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly I dont think there is. Although I am sure you can find tools to allow you to create the workflow between screens of your application.

Comment: any names of these tools please ?

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**

> Navigation Editor isn't available in Android Studio starting from
>   version 2.0. It was an experimental feature and we may re-visit it in
>   the future. Information on this page is left for archive purposes.

---

Android tools team just launched an early prototype of Navigation Editor for Android Applications, which they're planning to release next year

As of now, it'll be available to try/use in Android Studio.

Get all the information on Android tools website: http://tools.android.com/navigation-editor

Comment: it looks like a good start, but it's still useless.

Comment: The purpose of Navigation editor is the opposite. They generate the UI editor from your existing code, so it is more like a viewer. Storyboards replaces your code with the visual UI, which is much more helpful.

Comment: Navigation Editor has been discontinued with Android Studio 2.0: "Navigation Editor isn't available in Android Studio starting from version 2.0. It was an experimental feature and we may re-visit it in the future. Information on this page is left for archive purposes."